# Unauthorized 401 on Post request Windows Authentication + Core 2.2 WebAPI

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm using .CORE 2.2 with a WebAPI.
The solution is hosted on IIS10 Windows Server 2016 and Windows Authentication should be the only authentication method for my services.
In Angular 7 when I make the GET request using the option withCredentials set to true. everything works as expected. It doesn't work anyway with this Post request and the response is Unauthorized 401.
Just for information the APi and the Server API reside on a different server.

```
post<T>(path, body = {}): Observable<T> {
   let requestheaders = new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
   });
   return this.http.post(this.getUrl(path), '{}', 
   { headers: requestheaders, withCredentials: true }) as Observable<T>;
}
```

It's not the Cors Policy since the Cors is correctly configured

```
services.AddCors(options => options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy",
builder =>
{
      builder.WithOrigins("http://localhost:4200", 
            "https://localhost:4200")
            .AllowAnyHeader()
            .AllowAnyMethod()
            .AllowCredentials();
}));
```

and

```
app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");
```

Any clue about how to manage this issue ?

Comment: Can I see your API method.  I think you might be missing the [FromBody]

Answer (score 0):

- In your backend, Set the **AllowCredentials** or **SupportsCredentials** property to true
- In your backend, **do not** put wildcard (`*`) in allow origin. Add your frontend URL specifically

Something like this

.NET Core

```
services.AddCors(c =>
{
   c.AddPolicy("AllowOrigin",
       options => options
              .WithOrigins("http://localhost:4200") //Important
              .AllowAnyMethod()
              .AllowAnyHeader()
              .AllowCredentials() //Important
    );
});
```

or

```
 services.AddCors();

     var policy = new Microsoft.AspNet.Cors.Core.CorsPolicy();

     policy.Headers.Add("*");    
     policy.Methods.Add("*");          
     policy.Origins.Add("*");
     policy.SupportsCredentials = true;

     services.ConfigureCors(x=>x.AddPolicy("mypolicy", policy));
```

.NET 4.6

```
[EnableCors(origins: "http://localhost:4200", headers: "*", methods: "*", SupportsCredentials = true)]
```

Comment: Thanks for Your comment but sadly ..no it's not the cors policy since I already configured it that way. I updated my question now

Comment: Made some changes, can you just try adding `SupportsCredentials ` like this.. Actually I have achieved the same thing in .NET 4.6, not core

Comment: I don't have Microsoft.AspNet in my libraries only AspNetCore. Also I think AllowCredentials() and SupportCredentials are the same only the .NET version is different. Maybe the problem is that both server and client are under a VPN.

Comment: Hmm.. May be.. Hope you find the solution :)